# Leer xml sin ruta

Tags: c#, xml, windows-forms

Que tal buen día, he visto muchos ejemplos de como leer archivos  xml, pero lo hacen a partir de la ruta del archivo. Sin embargo yo quiero buscar los archivos xml. con el OpenFileDialog (Cabe recalcar que los xml tienen la misma estructura, los nodos no cambian solo los datos).
 Este es mi ejemplo de mi archivo xml:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora les mostrare mi código lo que estoy tratando de hacer:

```
  private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();



        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Prueba";
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|Todos los archivos (*.*)|*.*";
        OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;


        if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {

                if ((myStream = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(""); //Aquí pondría la ruta de origen del archivo pero eso no es lo que yo quiero.
                    string etiquetafinal = "";
                    while (xmlTextReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {
                            rtxt1.Text += (new string(' ', xmlTextReader.Depth * 3) + "<" + xmlTextReader.Name + ">");
                            etiquetafinal = xmlTextReader.Name;
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                        {
                            rtxt1.Text += xmlTextReader.ReadContentAsString() + "</" + etiquetafinal + ">";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rtxt1.Text += "\r";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
             }


    }
```

Espero me entiendan, quiero buscar el archivo xml y leerlo. gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenFileDialog tiene una propiedad llamada  [`FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) donde al momento de seleccionar el archivo, tendra la ruta del mismo:

```
if ((myStream = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
{
    // le envias el filename
    XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName); 
//...
```

En caso de que el usuario pueda seleccionar mas de 1 archivo, entonces puedes utilizar [`FileNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames(v=vs.110).aspx), que seria un array de string de los archivos seleccionados:

```
if ((myStream = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
{

    foreach(string filename OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
    {

        // le envias el filename
        XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(filename); 
        //...
```